# VMWare VSphere - Cluster de várias máquinas

Tags: vmware

Estou tentando entender o conceito do VMWare VSphere. Até onde já consegui ver na documentação e em vídeo-aulas, por exemplo tenho uma máquina de 5TB HD e 32 GB de RAM. Nessa máquina instalo o sistema operacional Vsphere. Em cima desse sistema operacional crio minhas máquinas virtuais. Lembrando que tenho pra distribuir pra minha máquinas virtuais os recursos da minha máquina física: 5TB HD e 32 GB de RAM.
Agora vem minha dúvida: tenho outra máquina física, com 8TB de HD e 16GB de RAM.
Quero "agregar" essa máquina pra que os recursos dela (HD e RAM, por exemplo) sejam somados aos recursos da primeira máquina física, e que assim possam ser também utilizados pelas máquinas virtuais. Ou seja, agora eu teria pra distribuir pras minhas máquinas virtuais 48GB RAM e 13TB de HD.
Isso faz sentido, ou meu conceito de VMWare vsphare está completamente equivocado? Realmente tem como "somar" duas máquinas físicas num sistema VMWare VSphare?

Answer (score 1):

Paulo, sua duvida é bem interessante, quando falamos de um cluster VMware seus recursos podem ser somados mais virtualmente, mesmo tendo uma maquina de 32 gb de memória e outra com 16, não ira inicialmente conseguir criar uma de 48 gb memória, caso isso seja necessário  pela sua aplicação pode utilizar outro tipo de recurso como cluster, como cluster de SQL server ou outro tipo de aplicação tendo 3 maquinas com 16 gb de memória totalizando os 48. 
Em algumas visões o Vcenter chega a demostrar esses recursos juntos porem voce deve dividir eles entre as VMs do seu cluster.